# PrestoDB: Filter to get rows where element is contained in map column's keys

Tags: presto

I have a column of type map(varchar, varchar). I would like to filter on the keys of the map to get rows of the table where the map contains a given string.

How do I check whether a varchar is contained in the keys of a map type column?

Answer (score 0):

## Get rows with a certain string (varchar) / strings as keys

```
select * from planet
where map_keys(tags) = ARRAY['barrier'];
```

## Get rows where an array column contains a particular string (varchar)

```
select * from planet
where contains(map_keys(tags), 'barrier');
```

In this case,

1. table name: planet
2. schema of column "tags": map(varchar, varchar)
3. String I was searching for in column tags: 'barrier'